# Is there any software that will let me "dock" or lock apps to the corners of the desktop in Windows 7/8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

For example, I am always fiddling with Spotify to get it exactly in the corner. Some apps, like Steam, lock into a corner when they are dragged close enough. Is there any way to get all apps to behave like this?

Comment: Spotify always does that, even the Winkey+up/down combos do not work, it's irritating

Answer (score 2):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) does that and more. The official use was meant to provide extra functionality for dual monitor set up. However, there is an option called "sticky" that provides exactly what you're looking for. Windows will "stick" to each other and edges of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

[WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) would do it for you.

> WinSplit Revolution is a small utility which allows you to easily organize your open windows. WinSplit Revolution is especially useful for high-end LCD screens with high resolutions because it helps you to efficiently manage many active windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try object dock

[A dock from stardock.com](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use different type of docks which are found [HERE](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/06/5-amazing-dock-application-for-windows-7-ultimate-tweak-all-free/) to well arrange all things.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Preme](http://www.premeforwindows.com/) for Windows 7? I used this a while back and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD graphics card you may look to see if you have the Catalyst software installed. I think it may be called Catalyst Control Center.  NVIDIA has similar software. It may already be installed on your system and if so it is usually revealed through display settings. In the past I've used both types of cards/software. They have docking and other window management features, e.g., multi-desktop, throwing windows to a second display.

Regardless, consider going to the support site of who makes your GPU. Look at the downloads/drivers section for your card. See what they have available.